# .htaccess exception to particular folders

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel

Here is my .htaccess code which is located in the root folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/blog/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here i am adding `/public` for all the url requests (also public/blog)

I need to add a new folder named as `code` to the public folder there this .htaccess rule should not apply. (It should like regular file system)

How can i exclude the rules for particular folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert this rule **just below `RewriteEngine On` line**:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /code
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: @Bizz mark his answer as answered if this solved the issue :)

Comment: Just now,i faced the issue, after adding the code you provided below to the RewriteEngine On, The main folder got affected. Is it possible to add the code you provided without affecting the old one's functionality ?

Comment: This rule only affect a request that had `/code` in URL. How can it affect anything else?

Comment: I have implemented the .haccess just inside my localhost/.htaccess Where i don't want to enter /public or /blog , after giving this rule, when i try to enter just localhost it just displays the files (before it was taking me inside /public )

Comment: But how is `code` related to `public`? **This rule only affects a request that had /code in URL, nothing else.** Feel free to open a new question with a link to this one and provide your latest .htaccess. Sometimes it is not easy to understand a problem from comments section.

Comment: Thanks, i shall ask in a new question. So, that i will be easy to understand :)

Comment: sure let me take a look