# .htaccess exception makes issue on main directory

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, laravel

Here is my Directory Structure

```
localhost or livehost
-app
-bootstrap
-public
-vendor
-code
-demo
```

Here is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/blog/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here is my route

```
Route::get('/', 'Sys@Home');
Route::get('blog', 'Sys@Blog');
Route::get('contact', 'Sys@Contact');
```

To access these , I don't want to enter my url as

```
localhost/public/
localhost/public/blog
localhost/public/contact
```

Instead its enough to enter as

```
localhost
localhost/blog
localhost/contact
```

At the same time, it should not apply to these to folders `/code` and `/demo` to access the directory.

So I got to write exception to these directories from this question [.htaccess exception to particular folders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27279825/4047397)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteRule %{THE_REQUEST} /code
    RewriteRule %{THE_REQUEST} /temp
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/blog/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

After applying this I can able to access the folder `localhost/code` and

```
localhost/demo
```

But I can't able to access the folder like

```
localhost
localhost/blog
localhost/contact
```

How can i make it both possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(code|tmp) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I can able to access code , tmp folder, but while i type localhost/ i just list the directory, i mean the /public ruleis not applying

Comment: No, i mean to say i can't able to use the `localhost/blog` which gives the usage of `localhost/public/blog`

Comment: But `localhost/public/blog` is working and `localhost/blog` is not working,, that's my issue :(

Comment: Yes, that's it i don't have any other code or any other .htaccess inpublic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67048/discussion-between-anubhava-and-bizz).

Comment: Hi, i have a question which is continuity of this one. Can you help me in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28053569/htaccess-makes-cause-in-the-sub-folder