# .htaccess causes issues in sub-folders

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my .htaccess to rewrite public/index.php 
I'm using the Laravel php framework.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(code|tmp) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Here the folders 'code' and 'tmp' can be accessed like normal.

If I add a set of nested folders, and add the default Laravel htaccess to remove the public/index.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It doesn't work inside the nested folder.

It works good if I don't have the firstly given .htaccess in the root directory. Once I given my .htaccess it is not working.

Is the .htaccess in the root directory causing effect to the sub folder ?

If so , how can I fix that

Note : This is the question where I got .htaccess previously

[.htaccess exception makes issue on main directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27511110/htaccess-exception-makes-issue-on-main-directory)

Comment: What are paths of each .htaccess?

Comment: The first path of first .htaccess is at `root` folder and second one is inside `root/code` folder (To say it was inside the htdocs -- The same was to be followed on live too i.e., `mydomain.com` & `mydomain.com/somefolder` )

Comment: Clearly tell which URLs are not working for you

Comment: localhost/code is not working for me (If i have the first htaccess in the root folder) .. Then i just deleted the .htaccess in the root folder localhost/code works good .. (The localhost url is working perfect)

Comment: If you have `/code/.htaccess` present then root .htaccess won't be read.

Comment: It's still reading sir :( Do you have teamviewer sir, because it's very hard to explain ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69335/discussion-between-chennai-city-gangsta-and-anubhava).